# What other definitions of NULL were there on older platforms?

Tags: c, standards, null-pointer

Occasionally, one reads that older C compilers had definitions of `NULL` that were not `0` or `(void *)0`. My understanding of the C standard was that even if the platform's bit pattern for a null pointer is nonzero, an integer 0 cast to a pointer (either implicitly or explicitly) is still a null pointer, and is stored internally as the platform's null pointer bit pattern.

But for example, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/5604/) it is written:

> In some older C compilers, `NULL` is variously defined to some weird things, so you have to be more careful with it.

I remember reading this in various other places from time to time. Unless this is a persistent urban legend, what other definitions of `NULL` have been in use?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that some systems used `0L` in the bad old days before the C standard.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I don't think the questions are duplicate. The other one is looking at horrible non-conforming definitions (at least according to the example in the question), whereas this one would be well answered with conforming but unusual definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right when you are saying that null-pointer constant (constant integral zero or constant integral zero cast to `void *`) is guaranteed to be properly converted to the appropriate internal representation of null pointer for the target type. Which means that there's no need for any other definition of `NULL`. `0` or `(void *) 0` will work everywhere.

However, at the same time, very early versions of C language did not make such guarantee and did not have a standard `NULL` macro. Assigning an integral value to a pointer variable caused the pointer to literally point to the address represented by that integral value. Assigning constant `0` to a pointer simply made it to point to address `0`. If users wanted to have a reserved pointer value in their program, they had to manually choose a "throwaway" address to use for that purpose.

It is quite possible that macro `NULL` came into informal usage before the standardization of the language and before the aforementioned zero-to-pointer conversion rule came into existence. At that time `NULL` would have to be defined as an integral value representing that exact reserved address. E.g. a pre-standard C implementation that wanted to use address `0xBAADFOOD` for null pointers would define `NULL` as `0xBAADFOOD`. I can't confirm that though, since I don't know when exactly macro `NULL` first appeared "in the wild".

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely correct.

One of the "weird things" you might encounter is #define'ing NULL to `((void *)0)`, which would cause code that used NULL as anything but a pointer to fail.

Here are a few other variations:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_null.htm

`#define NULL ((char *)0)`

or

`#define NULL 0L`

or

`#define NULL 0`

It's also worth noting that C++ 11 introduces `nullptr` to provide a type-safe disambiguation of NULL, 0, etc.  Refer to [Much Ado about Nothing](http://www.drdobbs.com/much-ado-about-nothing/184401802), or (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1601.pdf‎

Comment: And having code that abuses `NULL` fail is excellent!

Comment: Here are some good arguments for using "0" instead of NULL: [What other definitions of NULL were there on older platforms?](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/277583-does-null-need-a-header-or-did-i-mess-something-up/?view=findpost&p=2727022)

Comment: But having `char c = NULL;` generate a warning is better than letting it through uncommented upon.